# electric pair mode only inserts two double quotes after inserting a double quote in some buffers?

Tags: electric-pair-mode

I have `electric-pair-mode` on, but the behavior with double quotes is not working as expected in some buffers. In one of the affected buffers:

```
he said "
```

it does not insert the matching double quote when I type the `"` above. But I then type:

```
he said "hello world"
```

when I type that second `"`, it inserts another and I get:

```
he said "hello world""
```

That is: the matching double quote is only inserted at the end, or after inserting a starting double quote, or when not preceded by whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is from unbalanced quotes. For pairs with distinct beginning and end characters, such as parentheses, square brackets, curly brackets, curly quotes and so on, one can use `check-parens` or [something like this code](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_check_parens_balance.html) to check the buffer. But for `"` and `'` quotes, the best we can do is count them and see if the number is even. One can use some simple code like this:

```
;; perhaps a bit silly, but I like semantic names for my code, and it seems emacs lisp doesn't have these?
(defun even-p (n) (eq (mod n 2) 0))
(defun odd-p (n) (not (even-p n)))

(defun count-quote-occurrences ()
  "Count the occurrences of single and double quote characters in buffer.
If both values are even, display a message; otherwise, display a warning.
"
  (interactive)
  (let ((double-quote-occurences (count-matches "\"" (point-min) (point-max)))
        (single-quote-occurences (count-matches "\'" (point-min) (point-max))))
    (if (or (odd-p double-quote-occurences)
            (odd-p single-quote-occurences))
        (warn "Buffer contains %s double quotes and %s single quotes."
              double-quote-occurences
              single-quote-occurences)
        (message "Success: buffer contains %s double quotes and %s single quotes."
              double-quote-occurences
              single-quote-occurences))))
```

(amusingly, the above definition creates unbalanced double quotes, because it's not smart enough to handle the backslash escaping. So one could add a spurious " in a comment to fix that...)

...and if you get unbalanced quotes, use `occur` with the offending character and `M-g n` or similar to jump through the buffer and find where the quotes got unbalanced.

Comment: Note that in emacs lisp code, where one has docstrings the use backticks and single quotes, this won't work. Modifying the above code to handle a single quote as the end character for a either a backtick or starting single quote is left as an exercise to the reader...